# Como deletar um item de um objeto usando um ID interno (Vue-2)

Tags: javascript, objetos, vue.js-2

Tenho um objeto com o seguinte formato:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"exemplo1",
      "email":"exemplo1"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "name":"exemplo2",
      "email":"exemplo2"
   }
]
```

Preciso deletar um item deste objeto usando o **ID** interno dele.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
delete item da lista onde item.id == id
```

Estou usando o framework Vue-2 para exibir em uma tabela.

```
<tr v-for="{item, index} in list">
     <div @click="delete(item.id)"></div>
</tr>
```

**importante:** deletar o item usando o **index não serve**, eu preciso que seja com o ID.

Comment: Onde mora essa array? no `data` do componente? nas `props`? ou vem do servidor? E qual é a ação que faz essa remoção? é um `methods`?

Comment: @Sergio sim, esta dentro de um data e preciso remover com methods

Comment: estranha colocação `importante: deletar o item usando o index não serve, eu preciso que seja com o ID.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso seria percorrer toda a lista até encontrar o id procurado, para então remover esse elemento, segue um exemplo

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in lista" :key="index">
        <span>{{ item.valor }}</span><button type="button" @click="removerPorId(item.id)">Remover</button><br>
    </div>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        lista: [{
            id: 1,
            valor: 'Indice 1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            valor: 'Indice 2'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            valor: 'Indice 3'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            valor: 'Indice 4'
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            valor: 'Indice 5'
        }]
    },
    methods: {
        removerPorId: function (id) {
            var _vm = this; //Adicionando a instância à uma variável, para que possa ser acessada dentro do forEach`
            this.lista.forEach(function(el, index) {
                if(el.id === id)
                    _vm.lista.splice(index, 1);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Outra forma seria usar a função [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) para filtrar todos os elementos que são diferentes daquele que se deseja remover (sugestão do [Sérgio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio))

```
//Apenas a função removerPorId reescrita com o filter
removerPorId: function (id) {
    this.lista = this.lista.filter(function(el) {
        return el.id !== id;
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, estava sofrendo com isso.